# Core Animation delegate not called

Tags: cocoa, macos, delegates, core-animation

I must be doing something wrong obviously.
My delegate doesn't get called when I set the frame of a view.

Frame version NOT working

```
-(void)someMethod {
    CAAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animation];
    [anim setDelegate:self];
    [[currentViewController view] setAnimations:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:anim forKey:@"frame"]];
    [[newViewController view] setAnimations:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:anim forKey:@"frame"]];

    [[[currentViewController view] animator] setFrame:currentTarget];
    [[[newViewController view] animator] setFrame:newTarget];
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)animation finished:(BOOL)flag {
    NSLog(@"Yep; works!");
}
```

Weirdly enough; the same code using alphaValue does work:

```
-(void)someMethod {
    CAAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animation];
    [anim setDelegate:self];
    [[currentViewController view] setAnimations:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:anim forKey:@"alphaValue"]];
    [[newViewController view] setAnimations:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:anim forKey:@"alphaValue"]];

    [[[currentViewController view] animator] setAlphaValue:0.5];
    [[[newViewController view] animator] setAlphaValue:0.5];
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)animation finished:(BOOL)flag {
    NSLog(@"Yep; works!");
}
```

Can you tell me what I am missing here? I just don't understand.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either use the animator *or* you use an explicit animation. In your case, since you want *-animationDidStop* to be called, don't use the animator. Also, you [shouldn't be trying to animate the frame in an explicit animation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2008/qa1620.html). Either animate the bounds *or* animate the position or you can animate both by adding them both to your view's layer. Change your code to something like this:

```
-(void)someMethod
{
    CABasicAnimation *boundsAnim = 
                        [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"bounds"];
    [boundsAnim setDelegate:self];
    [boundsAnim setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithRect:currentTarget]];
    [boundsAnim setToValue:[NSValue valueWithRect:newTarget]];

    CABasicAnimation *positionAnim = 
                        [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    [positionAnim setDelegate:self];
    [positionAnim setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithPoint:currentPosition]];
    [positionAnim setToValue:[NSValue valueWithRect:newPosition]];

    [[[currentViewController view] layer] addAnimation:boundsAnim forKey:nil];
    [[[currentViewController view] layer] addAnimation:positionAnim forKey:nil];
}
```

Since this is OSX, you will have to make sure your view's layer is layer backed. You do this by calling:

```
[[currentViewController view] setWantsLayer:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to have your delegate method fire using the animator to set your frame. To do this you add animations for `frameSize` and `frameOrigin` keys separately:

```
-(void)someMethod {
    CAAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animation];
    [anim setDelegate:self];

    [[currentViewController view] setAnimations:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:anim forKey:@"frameOrigin"]];
    [[currentViewController view] setAnimations:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:anim forKey:@"frameSize"]];
    [[newViewController view] setAnimations:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:anim forKey:@"frameOrigin"]];
    [[newViewController view] setAnimations:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:anim forKey:@"frameSize"]];

    [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
    [[[currentViewController view] animator] setFrame:currentTarget];
    [[[newViewController view] animator] setFrame:newTarget];
    [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)animation finished:(BOOL)flag {
    NSLog(@"Yep; works!");
}
```

In this example your delegate method will fire for each of the four animations. If you're repositioning the view without resizing, you don't need the `frameSize` animations.